# How to handle global when format is 'es'?

Tags: rollupjs

I have identified an Javascript library (incremental-dom) as both a global and external. I'm loading the library in a script tag.

When the rollup format is 'iife' the library in injected into the iife and everything works.

However when I use the 'es' format, the global is never referenced and the browser throws a type error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'incremental-dom'`

Here's my rollup.config.js file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const root = process.cwd();
const string = require('rollup-plugin-string');
const superviews = require('rollup-plugin-superviews');

export default [
  {
    input: path.resolve(root, 'src', 'idx-admin-tab', 'component.js'),
    plugins: [
      superviews({include: 'src/**/*.html'}),
      string({include: ['src/**/*.css', 'src/**/*.svg']})
    ],
    globals: {'incremental-dom': 'IncrementalDOM'},
    external: ['incremental-dom'],
    output: {
      file: path.resolve(root, 'dist', 'idx-admin-tab.es.js'),
      format: 'es'
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals` only works in the context of `iife` or `umd` output — if you're creating an `es` bundle, it will simply be ignored.

If you wanted to just use the browser's native `import` support, you would have to turn the module specifier `incremental-dom` into one that the browser can resolve — something like this:

```js
export default [
  {
    // ...
    external: ['incremental-dom'],
    paths: {
      'incremental-dom': '/node_modules/incremental-dom/dist/incremental-dom.js'
    },
    // ...
  }
];
```

Unfortunately incremental-dom doesn't have an ESM build, so you can't `import` it. So if you don't want to bundle it, you will have to trick Rollup into using the global `IncrementalDOM` even in `es` mode.

You should be able to do that with [rollup-plugin-virtual](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-virtual):

```js
export default [
  {
    // ...
    plugins: [
      superviews({include: 'src/**/*.html'}),
      string({include: ['src/**/*.css', 'src/**/*.svg']}),
      virtual({
        'incremental-dom': 'export default window.IncrementalDOM'
      })
    ],
    // ...
  }
];
```